# I am unable to run gs:import in WPS Request Builder

Tags: geoserver, wps

I am using the GeoServer version but in that I want to use subprocess for that I have used `gs:import` but the subprocess is not working. It is giving error while in the other version of GeoServer 2.8. It is working perfectly. I can not get this issue that why my GeoServer is not able to perform the subprocess.

Comment: Welcome to Geographic Information Systems! Welcome to GIS SE! We're a little different from other sites; this isn't a discussion forum but a Q&A site. Your questions should as much as possible describe not just what you want to do, but precisely what you have tried and where you are stuck trying that. Please check out our short [tour] for more about how the site works.

Comment: what is the error message? what is the request you are sending? which version are you actually using?

Comment: i am using 2.15.2 version. when i select gs:import and after that i select subprocess and in subprocess i select the option application/xml as output format and after when i run that process it gives me error "Failed to parse Inputs" while it is working fine in the version 2.8 of geoserver

Comment: please use the [edit] button to update your question - as to why it's changed it's hard to say what changed in 7 major version changes